# How to find ordered pairs in smallest transitive relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Let R={(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(2,1)} . How many ordered pairs belong to the smallest transitive relation Rt that contains R?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to MSE!
You must transitively close the relation. Here:

$(1,2),(2,3)\in R$ require to add $(1,3)$.

$(2,3),(3,4)\in R$ require to add $(2,4)$.

$(1,2),(2,1)\in R$ require to add $(1,1),(2,2)$.